# Add text to element after submitting form in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm using the jQuery function *.submit()* on a form and I need to change text of already created element with function *.text()* after this form is submitted, but it doesn't work.

Code looks like this:

```
$('form').submit(function (){
    var text = "error";
    $('p.error').text(text);
});
```

If i get that *.text()* function out of the *.submit()* function, it works well, but I need to call it after submitting.

It seems like it refreshes the page after submitting and text changing, so the text there is lost. Is there any way how to fix it?

Comment: this is fired before the form is submitted - you might want to look at `$.ajax`.

Comment: You'll need to either 1) prevent the page refresh (use an ajax form submit), or 2) update the element with server-side code or URL parameters when the page refreshes.

Comment: Do you not want the form to submit? If not, check out jQuery's event.preventDefault()

Comment: most likely you need to add code for next page load. means the page after completion of form submit.

Comment: Why dont u use aJaX ? Its popular and FREE :) And looks cooler than Page Reloading Submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `preventDefault` on the submit event. Your code is more than likely working, but the page is reloading and making it seem like it isn't.

Try this:

```
$('form').submit(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var text = "error";
  $('p.error').text(text);
});
```